# How to create 'select by attributes' feature layer when greyed out? File is a feature class (not a feature layer) and I cannot convert it

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, attribute-joins, feature-class, subset

[image]I have a subset of attributes selected from a query in 'Select by Attributes' in the Attribute Table. I want to export these selected attributes into a new layer, and am unable to do so in ArcGIS Pro (it's greyed out when I right click on the layer > data > export features).

I tried the Feature Class to Feature Layer tool and it didn't create a layer I could save as it's own new shapefile.

Ideally, I want to create a new shapefile of the selected attributes and then add a separate shapefile to it (append it in the Attribute Table). The other shapefile is one created based on XY data (locations of universities).

Any advice? I would prefer not to have to create a brand new shapefile manually (where, I create a new dataset of XY locations for colleges and universities when the shapefile already exists).

Comment: Please provide some info about the data. Is the data local (GDB featureclass, shapefile, etc.) or online (web FeatureServer, OGC WFS, etc.)? Looks like the map you are using is a [web map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=385d5b830acc4d4ba9572fd885844cc6)? If your data is a local format, have you tried adding it to a new empty ArcGIS Pro project?

Comment: In the table of Contents, just below the Search field, select the first button on the left in the row of buttons.  This is the normal way of viewing layers (in the order they are shown on the map, hierarchically and whether they are hidden or not).  The Contents button your are currently using is for showing which layers are selectable.  I don't know if this will fix your issue, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Copy Features" tool or any of the "Feature to Polygon", "Feature to Point", etc tools. All of these will honor the selection that you have in the query.  This will allow you to create a new feature class. Is there a reason you specifically need a shapefile?